# Xcode 10.1 - HIgh Sierra - RealmSwift build failed with lots of error

Tags: xcode, realm

I am looking for an alternative to mongod and nodejs on the mac so I installed Cocoapods (via gem) and imported RealmSwift into a Xcode projet. I have try to build my project using the workspace but it gives plenty of errors. No matters what I try to resolve them (update pods, update ruby, update brew, modify pods config file,...) they are still there.

Maybe someone could tell me what is wrong or what would be the right installation procedure in my case (High Sierra - Xcode 10.1 - ios 11.0).

Thanks a lot.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqGCq.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dReDK.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzd7Z.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulaCu.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/anJV5.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZbIG.png
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi9fn.png
```

Comment: I was not able to include a link to the pictures in the code, sorry for this inconvenient.

Comment: The question is unclear. You are *replacing* mongod with MongoDB Realm? Also, please don't use links in questions. It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please include your Podfile as well.